# I do not know why the graph is not compiling and executing code for long time

Tags: python

There is no error in code ( I believe)

but when I run the program, the graph does not print in the plot. It just says executing code 
and i've waited like an hour but doesn't show anything.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
excel_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)

bool_idx = excel_df < 0.006

valid_data = excel_df[bool_idx]

true_data = valid_data.dropna()

tt = np.array(true_data.iloc[0:-1, 0])
print(tt)
tt2 = np.array(true_data.iloc[1:, 0])
print(tt2)
ts = abs(tt - tt2)
print(ts)
ind = np.array(np.where([ts < 0.001]))
graph1 = plt.plot(ind)
print(ind)
true_data0001 = true_data.iloc[0, ind]

print(true_data0001)
```

no error

Comment: you forgot `plt.show()` at the end.

Comment: doesn't work. ...

Comment: do you see any text from `print()` ? How big is csv file ?   Can you add you csv? Do you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error message ?

Comment: Exception ignored in: <generator object _process_plot_var_args._grab_next_args at 0x0956F430>
MemoryError: 
MemoryError

Comment: do you see any text from print() ? Do you can say which line makes problem ? How big is csv file ? Did you try with smaller file ?

Comment: I think the size of the csv is the problem.

Comment: so try with smaller file to confirm it. If you have too much point to display then maybe you should group points and calculate mean value to create less points.